# ModalPopupExtender blank x and y coordinates

Tags: c#, css, modalpopupextender

I have a ModalPopupExtender like that:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"
                        runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel" OkControlID="btnOkay" TargetControlID="Bt_Open_Dialog"
                         PopupControlID="Panel1" Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"  
                         X="400" Y="400"
                         >
 </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

When the application runs and the ModalPopup is opened the html/css made for the Panel is:

```
<div class="popupConfirmation" style="position: fixed; z-index: 100001; left: 400px; top: 400px;" id="Panel1">
```

But what i actually want is the 'left' and 'top' attributes (the X and Y coordinates) not present!

```
<div class="popupConfirmation" style="position: fixed; z-index: 100001;" id="Panel1">
```

This is a problem because if X and Y are not set, some random value is always put by the compiler and it is not possible write blank coordinates.

Do you know something to do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question.
It is not the cosiest way but it works in my situation.

With the ModalPopupExtender i manage an iframe, so via javascript, in the onload event I get the panel and manually erase the attributes.

```
var pnl = document.getElementById('Panel1');
pnl.style.left = "";
pnl.style.top = "";
```

However in my page I had a boring side-effect: you could see the iframe loading in the first position (the x and y attributes are still present) and moving to the right position when the page ended loading (because the css is updated via js in that momement).

So i had to write code to set the visibility as well.